# Explain how nav menu automatically fits/resizes on windows resize

Tags: jquery, css

On the following website, http://www.halogensoftware.com/uk, in the top section of the page, there is:

1. The company logo
2. The navigation menu
3. A navigation icon

[Full sized layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbipf.png)

When the browser window is resized (smaller), at the point the navigation bar "touches" the logo, it resizes automatically to fit.

Shrinking the window further (again to the point of the logo and navigation bar touching), it hides altogether.

What technique is used here please to accompany this "smart" resizing?  I know how to use JQuery/CSS3 in general, but cannot figure out how the available/used space is calculated and the menu resized (it might not even be either of these technologies).  I've tried inspecting in Firebug, but cannot figure out the approach.

Thank you.

Comment: Using JQuery, you can use `$(window).resize()` event to get when the window is resized. From this, you'll have to check the width you want (either calculate it at runtime or check it by hand with your browser's element inspector).

Comment: It is not only JQuery/CSS, You must define how your web page should look like based on the window size. Depending on the screen size you will determine what and how to render. If you see that page, when you resize some items desappears, some other are rendered different. As you see, it is a design desicion. Once you have defined how it should like depending on the differents screen sizes you will support, you can take advantage of some CSS techniques to do things easier., like @media.

Comment: My question really (given that I don't see Flex used in the CSS) is how they judge the appropriate window size at which to trigger a re-layout?  All fonts render at slightly different sizes across different platforms, so I don't get how it resized at exactly the right point every time...

Answer (score 1):

They are using [CSS @media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). No JS necessary to lay things out differently - they just size the browser down and whereever the layout starts to cause things to get close and overlap, then they define a @media query breakpoint there to lay things out differently with CSS. The only JS/jQuery necessary is writing something to serve as a click handler for the hamburger icon/menu to toggle the nav menu open/closed in a mobile view.

Here's a quick example.

```js
$('.burger').on('click',function() {
  $('nav').toggleClass('open');
})
```

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
body {
  padding: 2em 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.burger {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-radius: .25em;
  background: transparent;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  header {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  } 
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  header {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  nav {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0; right: 0;
  } 
  nav li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
    padding: .5em 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  }
  .burger, .open {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>logo</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <button class="burger">&#9776;</button>
</header>
```

Comment: Okay thanks.  However, you are using Flex, and I don't see that in their code.  So the "magic" my question is based on is how do they "know" at what point to resize the nav bar?  Your code works great, but because of the awful IE9- support I was keen to see exactly what their approach was.

Comment: @ForeverLearning re: flex, yeah I didn't use the same exact CSS they did, but it doesn't matter. I could easily use floats or something instead and the techniques would all be the same. The "magic" and how they "know" at what point to resize is unknown unless you ask them. As far as their code is concerned, all they're doing is using media queries. The way you know where to define breakpoints is by resizing the browser(s) and finding where the layout breaks - that's where you define a media query.